# Google chart: How to arrange months in chronological order

Tags: google-sheets

Base table with data is present. I have created a pivot and a chart from the pivot table. The month arranges in alphabetical order in the table rather than chronological order. Is there any way to arrange the data in chronological month order. This does not bring out the correct picture of the trend through the months.

Comment: Can you update the question to show a sample of the data and code you're using (such as how you've stored the date information)?

Comment: We have used the data validation on the date column. Date is divided into 3 columns: date, month, year. A pivot is taken on this table consisting of Month and total column. A graph is drawn on this pivot table.

Answer (score 0):

You can arrange in chronologic order very easy, but it depends on the format of your column 'Month'. 
You can see an example in this spreadsheet. 
[Spreadsheet to order months](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14nfXdgPTwgHo3QIBGHGdXKQB-dIQA1obWU8iFqrJgl4/edit#gid=0)

You said you have 3 columns: 'Date' (Date validation) | 'Month' | 'Year'

If 'Month' and 'Year' are dates themselves or a reference of the relative 'Date' cell (eg. Date in 'A1', so 'B1' is '=A1') using the 
Date formatting as MMMM *September* and YYYY *Year(1930)* (Menu/Format/Number/More Formats/More date and time format) then you can filter the header and press on *Sort A>Z*. It will sort them chronologically.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible. You need to convert those 3 fields into a field of type "date" by concatenating the values (with separator), because a date field takes a full date. Sorting full dates will be correct, in the correct order of the months.

Then you can

- either change which part of a date value is displayed in whatever format (but the underlying field value still needs to be a full date). For example, you could just show the name of the month if they are all from the same year.
- or show the full date in the table, but group the dates by month in the pivot table